# Informix CASE and summing results

Tags: subquery, case, informix

I have finally joined after many month of always getting my answer from here without having to ask but rather simply searching on here :).

I am fairly new to Informix and am struggling with my first CASE statement:

The rough idea of it is that I am awarding points based on revenue for a rewards program and two months in there are double point months.

My Select looks something like this:

```
Select  YearMonth,
    Account_Number,
    Customer_Name,
    Gross_Revenue,
    Gross_Revenue * BLC_multiplier BLC_Points
from    (
    Select  salesstat.year_num||salesstat.int_num YearMonth,
        Customer.cust_code Account_Number,
        Customer.name_text Customer_Name,
        sum(salesstat.net_amt-salesstat.return_net_amt) Gross_Revenue,
        CASE
        WHEN
            salesstat.int_num in (4,8)
        THEN
            .02
        ELSE
            .01
        END BLC_multiplier
    from    Customer,
        salesstat,
        warereptdetl,
        Product,
        maingrp
    Where   product.cmpy_code = 'AB'
    and Product.part_code = salesstat.part_code
    and salesstat.cmpy_code = 'AB'
    and customer.cmpy_code = 'AB'
    and customer.cust_code = salesstat.cust_code
    and salesstat.rept_code = '0'
    and warereptdetl.ware_code = salesstat.ware_code
    and warereptdetl.cmpy_code = 'AB'
    and salesstat.year_num||salesstat.int_num in ('201412','20151','20152','20153','20154','20155','20156','20157','20158','20159')
    and salesstat.ord_ind in ('7','8')
    and salesstat.stat_type_code = 'MLY'
    and salesstat.int_num > 0
    and warereptdetl.warereptgrp_code in('NSW','MNW')
    and maingrp.maingrp_code = salesstat.maingrp_code
    and maingrp.cmpy_code = 'AB'
    and customer.ref6_code = 'BLC'
    and customer.ref7_code in ('Y','U')
    and customer.cust_code in ('408759','112348')
    group by YearMonth,
        Customer.cust_code,
        Customer.name_text,
        BLC_multiplier
    Order by YearMonth asc,
        Customer.cust_code asc
    )
```

I wanted to do it all in one go something like:

```
Select  salesstat.int_num MonthValue,
        sum(salesstat.net_amt-salesstat.return_net_amt) Gross_Revenue,
        sum(salesstat.net_amt-salesstat.return_net_amt) *
        CASE
        WHEN
            salesstat.int_num in (4,8)
        THEN
            .02
        ELSE
            .01
        END BLC_Points
```

but when I do it tells me that BLC_Points needs to be in the group by (which it can't because it is an aggregate field)

I also tried:

```
Select  salesstat.int_num MonthValue,
        sum(salesstat.net_amt-salesstat.return_net_amt) Gross_Revenue,
        CASE
        WHEN
            salesstat.int_num in (4,8)
        THEN
            sum(salesstat.net_amt-salesstat.return_net_amt) * .02
        ELSE
            sum(salesstat.net_amt-salesstat.return_net_amt) * .01
        END BLC_Points
```

Whilst my fix DOES WORK, I want to make sure I am doing it properly. Incorrect code is hard to maintain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow as a poster.  Your top query is missing a lot of SQL (a close parenthesis, at least one GROUP BY clause, probably WHERE clauses, and so on).  Can you provide the rest of the query, and an outline schema of the table (or tables) that we need, preferably with a few rows of sample data and the desired result for those rows?

Comment: It is a good idea to use a minimum of code -- that's called creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  However, it is necessary to provide code that is complete enough to be comprehended, and I've no clue what you're doing because the FROM clauses are incomplete or missing.  So, remove as much as possible, but make it workable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jonathan, I will make sure I always post a more comprehensive query going forwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note JL's comments in your question, and agree that is all very good advice.

Long story short, you cannot use labels/aliases for columns or expressions in the `GROUP BY` clause. The simple solution is to use the ordinal position alternative: `GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4`

---

For what it's worth, an alternative to the `CASE` statement that I prefer for legibility would be:

```
DECODE(salesstat.int_num,
       4, 0.2
       8, 0.2
       0.1) AS BLC_Points
```

(Do with that last bit as you please.)

Comment: I needed to add salesstat.int_num to the group by clause but the decode does what I need

        DECODE(salesstat.int_num,
        4, sum(salesstat.net_amt-salesstat.return_net_amt) * 0.2,
        8, sum(salesstat.net_amt-salesstat.return_net_amt) * 0.2,
        sum(salesstat.net_amt-salesstat.return_net_amt) * 0.1) AS BLC_Points

Comment: Don't do that, it looks like a headache. Try simply: `DECODE(salesstat.int_num, 4, 0.2, 8, 0.2, 0.1) * SUM(salesstat.net_amt-salesstat.return_net_amt)`

Comment: Applied your suggestion and it's much cleaner.